# How to changes input required attribute in symfony2 form?

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm using a form on add and edit page in which there is a input file which is required for add record but it is not required on edit page. Is there a way to change attribute on different pages?

```
        $builder->add('title', 'text', array(
        'required' => true,
    ))->add('description', 'textarea', array(
        'required' => false,
    ))->add('fileName', 'file', array(
        'data_class' => null,
        'required' => true,
        'label' => 'Upload File'
    ));
```

this is my controller

```
        if ($custFile === null) {
        $custFile = new File();
    }

    $fileForm = $this->createForm(new CustomerFileType(), $custFile);
    $fileForm->handleRequest($request);
    if ($fileForm->isValid()) {
        $data = $fileForm->getData();
        $custFile->setUserType('customer');
        $custFile->setUserId($request->get('id'));
        $custFile->setDateAttached($data->date);

        $om->persist($data);

        $file = $custFile->getFileName();
        if ($file instanceof UploadedFile) {
            $uploadManager = $this->get('probus_upload.upload_manager.user_files');
            if ($newFileName = $uploadManager->move($file)) {
                $custFile->setFileName(basename($newFileName));
            }
        }

        $om->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('minicasp_customer_edit_customer', array(
                            'id' => $request->get('id'),
        )));
    }
            $fileRecord = array();
    if (null !== $customer) {
        $fileRecord = $om->createQueryBuilder()
                ->from('MinicaspCustomerBundle:file', 'f')
                ->select('f')
                ->where('f.userId = :customer')
                ->andWhere('f.userType = :userType')
                ->orderBy('f.id', 'DESC')
                ->setParameter('customer', $request->get('id'))
                ->setParameter('userType', 'customer')
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult()
        ;
    }

    return $this->render('MinicaspCustomerBundle:Default:customerAccount.html.twig', array(
                'form' => $form->createView(),
                'payment_form' => $paymentForm->createView(),
                'file_form' => $fileForm->createView(),
                'payments' => $payments,
                'file_record' => $fileRecord,
                'file_edit' => $fileEdit
    ));
```

Comment: Show us how you declare the form in controller in both actions edit and add

Comment: please check now, i've updated my description.

Comment: Same action for add and edit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Umair Malik, according to your last comment, you can try this in your controller:

```
if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
     $form->submit($request);

    $formData = $form->getData();
    if ($formData->getFile() !== null){
        /*
         * New file has been uploaded
         * Save or copy your old record; after this will be over-written
         */
    }

    $entityManager->persist($formData);                                
    $entityManager->flush(); 
}
```

Comment: yeah i want something like this, but how can i get that old record? i tried to search for that record by its id but its giving me record submitted from form. 
$customerRecord = $om->getRepository('MinicaspCustomerBundle:File')->find($id);

Comment: Get it before form is processed.

Answer (score 1):

Get your object inside form class and check if your add or edit new record, and based by this set the value of "required" attribute:

```
$obj = $builder->getData();

$builder->add('fileName', 'file', array(
    'data_class' => null,
    'required' => $obj->getId() === null ? true : false,
    'label' => 'Upload File'
));
```

Comment: Can you help me in another problem,

My requirement is when user edit a record it first check is user attached a file, if no, then it should update that record but if user attached a new file during edit it should add a new row with old record of that row and also it must update file name with new file he attached.

Comment: If I understood well, you want user to be able to add multiple files to a record. So, you need a "Upload new" button that actually add new upload input on click. After the form is submitted, you can have 1 or more files to upload and save. Right?

Comment: I want to maintain history of files uploaded by user so thats why i want when ever user try to edit his record and also file its old record sholud be saved first and then old record is updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two form types, with different options.

On a side note, you don't need to put "required => true"  that's the default option,